# netbeans 7.4 linux mint install error

Tags: linux, linux-mint, netbeans-7.4

I try install netbeans 7.4 for html5 and php develop version on Linux Mint 15 Olivia.But installer throw error wthi next message:

> *** Error in
>   `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/unpack200': double free or
>   corruption (out): 0x089f5720 ***
>   ======= Backtrace: ========= /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x767e2)[0xb765d7e2]
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77530)[0xb765e530]
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1(+0xd8fb)[0xb77a88fb]
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1(deflateEnd+0x3c)[0xb77a01dc]
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/unpack200[0x8057911]
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/unpack200[0x8057ad6]
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/unpack200[0x804eee0]
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/unpack200[0x8058adc]
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/unpack200[0x8048f87]
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0xb7600935]
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/unpack200[0x8048fad]
>   ======= Memory map: ======== 08048000-0805d000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 526424     /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/unpack200
>   0805d000-0805e000 r--p 00015000 08:08 526424
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/unpack200 0805e000-0805f000
>   rw-p 00016000 08:08 526424
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/unpack200 0805f000-08060000
>   rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  089ac000-08a16000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   [heap] b75ac000-b75c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393963
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 b75c7000-b75c8000 r--p 0001a000
>   08:01 393963     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 b75c8000-b75c9000
>   rw-p 0001b000 08:01 393963     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
>   b75e5000-b75e7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  b75e7000-b7795000 r-xp
>   00000000 08:01 397441     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
>   b7795000-b7797000 r--p 001ae000 08:01 397441
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so b7797000-b7798000 rw-p 001b0000 08:01
>   397441     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so b7798000-b779b000 rw-p
>   00000000 00:00 0  b779b000-b77b2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394091
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7 b77b2000-b77b3000 r--p 00016000
>   08:01 394091     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7 b77b3000-b77b4000
>   rw-p 00017000 08:01 394091     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.7
>   b77cd000-b77d2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  b77d2000-b77d3000 r-xp
>   00000000 00:00 0          [vdso] b77d3000-b77f3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01
>   397442     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so b77f3000-b77f4000 r--p
>   0001f000 08:01 397442     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
>   b77f4000-b77f5000 rw-p 00020000 08:01 397442
>   /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so bfa28000-bfa49000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   [stack]